# Collision matrix is set to have no interaction between layers, but collider still triggers

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I wanted to set up the layers that my Player interacts with, but it still triggers with unwanted layers. I have disabled the whole collision matrix in project settings:

[image: Blank layer collision matrix]

Here's my Player settings:

[image: Inspector for player object on player layer]

And ProjectileCleaner settings:

[image: Inspector for projectile cleaner object on projectile cleaner layer]

I have this script attached to the 'Player' gameObject, but my Player still triggers with the 'ProjectileCleaner' layer. Why?

```
public class PlayerCollisionController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("trigger: " + other.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some Layer Overrides enabled on collides?

Comment: @Nikaas nope, but thanks for the idea, I've just excluded the layer. Works fine.